# Leaflet does not mark point with geojsonFeatures?

Tags: javascript, json, leaflet, geojson

I'm starting on Leaflet API and I hope to add some geometry points to a customer map using `GeoJson` data. Currently, I used the `geojsonFeature`type present here http://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start.html

But, when I follow such steps to add the features, the ones does not appears. Below is my html page and code.

```
<html><head>
    <title>Leaflet Quick Start Guide Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.css">
</head>
<body class="">
    <div id="mapid" style="width: 600px; height: 400px; position: relative;" class="leaflet-container leaflet-fade-anim" tabindex="0"></div>

    <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="https://raw.github.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet-ajax/master/dist/leaflet.ajax.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

        L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/edsonbarboza/ciqb82pfe000dc1nliqy8sljp/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiZWRzb25iYXJib3phIiwiYSI6ImNpbTJjMWRuczA5NGx1MGtzbmN6c3NjOHMifQ.FvAMXzmnQ0TIJDDsV6rXAw', {
            maxZoom: 18,
            attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
                '<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
                'Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
            id: 'mapbox.satelity'
        }).addTo(mymap);


        var myStyle = {
        "color": "#ff7800",
        "weight": 5,
        "opacity": 0.65
        };


        //L.marker([51.51, -0.09]).addTo(mymap)

        var geojsonFeature = {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "name": "Coors Field",
                "amenity": "Baseball Stadium",
                "popupContent": "This is where the Rockies play!"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [51.51, -0.09]
            }
        };

        var myLayer = L.geoJson().addTo(mymap);
        myLayer.addData(geojsonFeature);

        <!-- var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("geojson_data.json", {style:myStyle}); -->

        <!-- geojsonLayer.addTo(mymap); -->

        var popup = L.popup();

        function onMapClick(e) {
            popup
                .setLatLng(e.latlng)
                .setContent("You clicked the map at " + e.latlng.toString())
                .openOn(mymap);
        }

        mymap.on('click', onMapClick);

    </script>
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

You must invert the coordinates in the geometry.

```
 var geojsonFeature = {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "name": "Coors Field",
            "amenity": "Baseball Stadium",
            "popupContent": "This is where the Rockies play!"
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [-0.09, 51.51]
        }
    };
```

Here is your [sample](http://plnkr.co/edit/HJRR7gyJTig0bLWygK8k?p=preview) with correction

This is specified [here](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#positions)

Comment: Thanks it does work. But with leaflet-ajax collect json FeatureCollection does not work

Comment: follow the example specified in [link](http://jsfiddle.net/ve2huzxw/197/) and my sample its on [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/Y90ic8unce0cZOwzrG2w?p=info)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. I don't see any problem. Look at this http://plnkr.co/edit/RtZL9YmlsTdbv3qJpW8e?p=preview where I just added your sample data in your original snippet

Comment: The problem is that the function in line 52 and 53 does not obtains all Feature Collections represented by Point geometry in the geojson file (geojson_data.json).

Comment: I find the problem [here](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4758/erro-com-navega%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ajax-xmlhttprequest-cannot-load). Basically, I forgot to running the app on a webserver. :)

Comment: That explains things :)